# How to make a function plot dynamic in a combined graphics?

Tags: graphics, dynamic

Here is the code:

```
Dynamic@Show[{Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{0, -1}, {Pi, 1}]}], 
   Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}]}]
Slider[Dynamic[a]]
```

The Slider controls the value of `a` in `Plot[]` to produce a dynamic plot of `Sin[]`.
I would like to make the `Plot[]` dynamic only, but it didn't work if i only wrapped `plot[]` with `dynamic[]`, so i added dynamic to the whole **show[]**. So how to dynamically update `plot[]` solely?

Comment: `Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, π}, PlotRange -> {{0, π}, {-1, 1}}, Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[{0, -1}, {π, 1}]}], {{a, 1}, -2, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: the code i posted in the question is a simplified example, the original code has combined graphics and plot, so it's unlikely to modify it by using Prolog.

Comment: Besides, the Prolog will be updated as well while the value of a changes, right? Because the whole Plot is dynamic.

Comment: `Slider[Dynamic[a]]`   `gr = Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{0, -1}, {Pi, 1}]}]; Dynamic[Show[gr, Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, Pi}]]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the `Graphics` expression in place, so that it just becomes a constant in the `Show` expression. Like so:

[image: stuff]